# Get total number of subscribed people to person with fql

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

I am currently finding the number of subscribers to a profile with the graph api, but in doing so many calls is very slow, so I would get all the numbers with a multiquery to optimize time

Answer (score 1):

Facebook returns the `total_count` when calling the user's `subscribers` [connection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#subscribers) so that is all you need.

If you need to make multiple calls then use the [Batch API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/).